# Using serial-input latches from Pi to drive 24V load (LEDs)

Tags: led, raspberry-pi, shift-register

**TL;DR**: LEDs when 'on' are great, however, they're too bright when they should be 'off'.

I'm trying to build a custom, large 7-segment LED display driven by a Raspberry Pi.
I'm a coder so the bit twiddling is the easy bit (although I'm very willing to believe I've screwed that up too :)), electronics ... not so much.

I'll eventually be using 21 LEDs per segment of the digit, split into 3 strings of 7 LEDs, so I need about 24V DC to power the LEDs.

I thought of using an [MIC5891](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/devicedoc/20005638a.pdf) in each of the digits because it promises latching, easy serial input with 5V logic supply, chaining and 'will sustain at least 35V in the on-state'.

Here's what my test board looks like:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6lLjI.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

All 'off' and the LEDs are very dim (about 1V) but acceptable.

If any of the 'segments' are lit, the ones which should be off are showing and I can record about 6v across them, so they're pretty bright :(

Just for my sanity here's the 21 LED segment setup.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fVtW6c.png)</sup>

I wonder if there's a grounding issue here, I keep seeing mention of pull-down resistors but always in the context of inputs.

Any advice very welcome -- it's driving me nuts :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fQ6ayB.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. OP's first schematic rearranged for clarity.*

> I wonder if there's a grounding issue here, I keep seeing mention of pull-down resistors but always in the context of inputs.

There's a grounding issue alright, but it's not to do with pull-down resistors. You have no ground connection between the two circuits. Connect the 24 V negative to the ground of the rest of the circuit.

Comment: Thanks @Transistor!
I was too tentative plugging in -24V into my Pi :)
Works like a charm.

Comment: Good. Just checking: do you understand why the absence of the ground link caused a problem? Some of the circuitry had no return path. To see it clearly you'd need to draw out one channel of the MIC5891 but the datasheet shows a common ground between the logic circuits and the outputs so that's what we've done here. Note the few simple improvements on the schematic. The GND symbol eliminates a bunch of wires / clutter and allows you to see the referenced voltage instantly. In general current should flow from top to bottom, hence the orientation of the LEDs and 24 V PSU.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR

The drivers are NPN Emitter Followers or high-side drivers that require common returns with logic ground.

-1st cct draws about 25mA which you can measure across series drop R using Ohm’s Law ... is ok but bright near abs. Max.
- 2nd cct draws (24-21)V/330 Ohms=12mA for a 3V drop. After you connect the shared grounds.

- IC is rated (while hot) for 800mA max continuous on all ports added up so , or 100 mA per port or 33mA per array or 11 mA per string of 3.

Since only 6 of 7 segments max will ever be driven, you can use the 12 mA you selected.

Coincidence or good plan? But pushing IC to max temp rise , so have convection air flow over it,  not sealed up.

- or use JB Weld epoxy thin layer to a heatsink to IC

YMW

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I'll bump the resistors up to bring the LED current down.

>> IC is rated (while hot) for 800mA max ...

I couldn't find the 800mA you mentioned, but my calcs are based on Ic = 500mA.

So for 7 segments => 71.4mA per segment => ~24mA per 'string' of 7 LEDs.

Now I've got the basics working I am now considering pulsing the device to reduce the load on the IC and putting a fat capacitor (technical term I'm sure) across the LEDs to smooth the pulse out (size yet to be determined).


>> Coincidence or good plan?
I'd like to think it was planned :)